# Not to able to get multiple records through poll api in confluent kafka python client

Tags: python-3.x, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am using  confluent kafka python library to consume messages, I want to get multiple records in poll call. but somehow I am getting only a single record at a time.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer

c = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': '127.0.0.1:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})

c.subscribe(['test-topic'])
while True:
    msg = c.poll(timeout=1.0)
    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        continue
    else:
        # Proper message
        print('%s [%d] at offset %d with key %s:' %
                         (msg.topic(), msg.partition(), msg.offset(),
                          str(msg.key())))

        msg = msg.value().decode('utf-8')
        print('Received message: {}'.format(msg))
```

Is there any confuration/parameter I need to pass to poll or is there any other API so that I can get multiple records in single poll call.

Comment: Are you continually ingesting messages to the topic? Is your timeout long enough for the ingestion rate?

Comment: I am continually ingesting  messages to the topic. Moreover I have tried with longer timeouts as well

Answer (score 1):

I found [consume](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#confluent_kafka.Consumer.consume) API that return multiple records.

> Parameters:    num_messages (int) – Maximum number of messages to return(default: 1).
>
> timeout (float) – Maximum time to block waiting for
> message, event or callback (default: infinite (-1)). (Seconds)
>
> Returns:   A list of Message objects (possibly empty on timeout)

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaException

consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': '127.0.0.1:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    "enable.auto.commit": "false",
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})

emptyPollLimit = 10
emptyPollCounter = 0

try:
    consumer.subscribe(['test-topic'])
    records = consumer.consume(timeout=1, num_messages=20)
    while emptyPollCounter < emptyPollLimit:
        print(records)
        if not records:
            print("no record found retrying {} times".format(emptyPollCounter + 1))
            emptyPollCounter += 1

        else:
            print("total records read: {}".format(len(records)))
            for record in records:
                print('topic: %s partition:%d at offset: %d with key: %s:' %
                      (record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(),
                       str(record.key())))
                record = record.value().decode('utf-8')
                print('Received message value: {}'.format(record))
        consumer.commit(async=False)
        records = consumer.consume(timeout=1, num_messages=20)

except KafkaException as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    # Close down consumer to commit final offsets.
    consumer.close()
```